# c#) How to refer to the contents of 1mb byte array, without copy new array

Tags: c#, arrays, offset

How to refer to the contents of 1mb byte array, without copy new array.

I searched some function like [ArraySegment].

But It supports only int type as offset.

I need to use long type as offset.

Comment: This question is lacking, what do you need to do with this referral. Likely `Span<T>` is a good solution. However the question is lack so much detail is hard to know what you actually want, what you are trying to do. or what the actual problem is

Comment: Why do you need a long for a 1mb array? Int supports up to 2gb?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but maybe the methods below are what you are looking for:

```
    public static void BaSetLong(byte[] byteArray, int longOffset, long value) {
        int start = longOffset * 8;
        byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) byteArray[start + i] = array[i];
    }

    public static long BaGetLong(byte[] byteArray, int longOffset) {
        int start = longOffset * 8;
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray, start);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what `Span<byte>` was invented for, though it was only introduced in netstardard 2.1.

If you can't use that, then you have to pass around a reference to the array, offset & length. Though you could create your own `Span` type.